# root password changed automatically

Tags: linux, security, password

I have my system on dual boot (win7 and RHEL 6).

I have 2 user account on RHEL 6. A normal user and a root user. I put passwords of both accounts same. It was working fine from 5 6 days. Yesterday I installed ntfs-3g to use NTFS drives in RHEL. It worked fine too. Now today's morning when I started my laptop, I login through the normal account, worked fine. Then I accessed NTFS drive, it asked for authentication, I gave root's password but it said that the password is wrong.

I will change the root's password from single user mode. But I just want to know why did this happen? How it changed automatically?

PS: No one else accessed my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

It probably did not change.

Its possible that its a PolicyKit setting. It's probably asking for your password to use sudo to grant you privileges not for root's password. Even if they are the same it may be trying to do this but you are not in the wheel group and so sudo does not work.

Run `visudo` as root and enable the group wheel to gain root permissions, then add yourself to that group and try again.

See `man 5 sudoers` and `man gpasswd` for the syntax.

Comment: root's password is not working, I am unable to login via root also.

Comment: hmm well thats very odd, you may have locked your account, what is the first line of /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow say?

Comment: root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash AND root:$6$kan......:15174:0:99999:7:::

Comment: I was not able to login through root because the password was not working, I changed it from single user mode and then I looked at the passwd and shadow file and then gave you what you wanted. But I think it will not work now.

Comment: if you reset the root passwd, and it still doesn't work, check you rgroups, and then sudo and Policy Kit settings

Comment: It's working after resetting, everything is fine now. I just want to know how did it changed before?